# Jagged Edges and Antialiasing In Viewport With Background Images

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, antialiasing

I am on the latest LTR build (2.83.1) and have noticed that any geometry that's drawn above a background image doesn't anti-alias properly. See image for example:

[image: Antialiasing Problems]

Does anyone know a fix for this? Is this happening to other people as well?

Answer (score 1):

Change the *Depth* of the reference images under *Object Data Properties* to *Back*

[image: Object Data Properties]